# How to show a date selected in Calendar?

Tags: magento-1.8, calendar

When we open date calendar, it shows current date selected by default. But I need to show a date selected which is 15 days ahead of current date.

My code

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" id="delivery_date" name="delivery_date">
```

Script:

```
   Calendar.setup({
                inputField: "delivery_date",
                ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y",
                showsTime: false,
                button: "delivery_date_trig",
                align: "Bl",
                singleClick : true
            })
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$("#delivery_date" ).datepicker("option", "defaultDate", +15);`

Comment: I cannot use datepicker. I need to use magento's default calendar only.

Comment: In which page actually you want this?

Comment: `$Today=date('y:m:d');
$NewDate=Date('y:m:d', strtotime("+15 days"));`

Answer (score 2):

not sure about this, but I think you can pass a `dateText` param to the setup.

```
Calendar.setup({
            inputField: "delivery_date",
            ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y",
            showsTime: false,
            button: "delivery_date_trig",
            align: "Bl",
            singleClick : true,
            dateText: 'your date here'
        })
```